# Не могу найти Путь к node.js

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, typescript, webstorm, nvm

Установила nvm и node с помощью ubuntu ( git почему-то не хотел устанавливать). Когда создаю проект в webstorm пишет ошибку,что надо указать путь к node.js .И как мне найти этот путь?[image: айти]

Comment: что значит "установила с помощью ubuntu"? У вас что за операционная система, как именно Вы установили node.js? Попробуйте в терминале выполнить команду `which node` - она должна вернуть путь к node executable; если не поможет - можно попробовать `which nodejs`

Comment: стоит Windows 10 . путь находит /home/irfedorova/.nvm/versions/node/v12.11.1/lib/node_modules . Но как этот путь вбить в webstorm

Comment: для этого существует поддержка node на wsl:)

Comment: Спасибо большое,благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно настроить WSL Node interpreter согласно инструкциям в https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2019.2/developing-node-js-applications.html#ws_node_wsl: в **Node.js Interpreters** добавьте WSL интерпретатор (**+**, **Add WSL**), выберите Ваш *Linux distribution* и укажите путь к интерпретатору

Answer (score 0):

#### Устанавливаем последнюю версию `node.js` в `ОС Linux`

1. Удаляем то, что установили из репозитория ОС.
2. Скачиваем с [официального сайта](https://nodejs.org) архив `.tar.gz` и распаковываем его в каталог `/opt`.
3. Создаем символическую ссылку `/opt/node` на папку с текущей версией нода (удобно потом менять будет при обновлении). Например:

   ```
   $  ln -s /opt/node-v12.11.1-linux-x64 /opt/node
   ```
4. Заходим в папку `/opt/node/bin/` и встречаем там 3 файла `node, npm, npx`. Создаем символические ссылки для них в папке `/usr/bin`:

   ```
   $  ln -s /opt/node/bin/node /usr/bin/node
   $  ln -s /opt/node/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm
   $  ln -s /opt/node/bin/npx /usr/bin/npx
   ```
5. Проверяем, что получилось, в консоли (должно показать текущую версию нода):

   ```
   $  node --version
   v12.10.0
   ```
6. Перезапускаем WebStorm.